# Neo4j parralel Reads and Bulk inserts

Tags: java, neo4j

Using Neo4j2.0 embedded in Java applications, How can I do 
both Bulk Inserts (10M nodes and 13M relations) every 5 mins in one Process and
Read operations on same database in other Process ?
While doing Inserts Database is locked and so unable to open connection for Read operations.

**For Inserts using**
*BatchInserter inserter = BatchInserters.inserter(...**

**And For Read using**

*GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );*

Please suggest if there is any alternative or if it is possible to disable Locking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't out of the box.

#### Snapshot inserts

Something you can do is to do the inserts with the batch-inserter reading from a queue.

And whenever you need a new snapshot of that imported data you shut down the batch-inserter, copy the database over to the transactional application and start it from that snapshot.

#### Use Transactional in one Process

Otherwise, just use the normal transactional API for both reading and writing.

As long as you batch-writes, e.g. 50k nodes/rels per batch, you should should be still fine, doing both from the same process.